# Data manipulation in csv using R

Tags: r, csv, reshape2

I'm currently working with data generated by eyelink. The csv (transformed from asc) is basically one large sequential list, i.e. columns are not created, so for example a row will have 'trial 1' and the following row will have x and y coordinates and the following N rows will also before coming to trail 2 row.

I was wondering if anyone has any advice on how to manipulate this 'stacked' data and transform it into long form data?

Here is what the data looks like when pulled from the csv and into a data frame in R. It only recognises 1 variable with N amount of observations:

```
> MSG.12892743.start_trial.1.SCNB
1   12892743      757.0   361.7  5916.0 ... SCNB
2   MSG 12892744 PreBeep1_1st_Sketchpad SCNB
3   12892744      756.7   361.7  5920.0 ... SCNB
4   12892745      756.1   362.2  5924.0 ... SCNB
5   MSG 12892746 order of frames:   SCNB
6   12892746      755.8   362.3  5928.0 ... SCNB
7   12892747      756.7   362.3  5927.0 ... SCNB
8   MSG 12892748 crosshair  SCNB
9   12892748      757.8   361.8  5928.0 ... SCNB
10  12892749      758.4   361.8  5930.0 ... SCNB
11  MSG 12892750 sketchpad  SCNB
12  12892750      758.1   361.7  5934.0 ... SCNB
13  12892751      758.3   361.7  5938.0 ... SCNB
14  MSG 12892752 sketchpad  SCNB
15  12892752      759.1   361.9  5948.0 ... SCNB
16  12892753      760.4   362.7  5956.0 ... SCNB
17  MSG 12892754 sketchpad  SCNB
```

Ideally I'd like to have individual columns for:

- Trial ID (SCNB shown above)
- Frame ID (PreBeep1_1st_Sketchpad above)
- X-CoOr (757.0 above)
- Y-CoOr (361.7 above)
- Time (5916.0 above)

Edit: Example of raw data as requested:

```
MSG 5410895 start_trial                         
MSG 5410895 PreBeep1_1st_Sketchpad                          
5410895 651.6   524.6   4372    ...             
5410896 651.6   525.3   4376    ...             
MSG 5410897 order of frames:                            
5410897 651.7   525.5   4377    ...             
5410898 651.8   525.9   4378    ...             
MSG 5410899 crosshair                           
5410899 652.1   526.1   4376    ...             
5410900 652.5   526 4373    ...             
MSG 5410901 sketchpad                           
5410901 653 525.6   4370    ...             
5410902 652.2   525.3   4366    ...             
MSG 5410903 sketchpad                           
5410903 651.1   524.7   4364    ...             
5410904 650.9   524.2   4366    ...             
MSG 5410905 sketchpad                           
5410905 651.6   523.7   4368    ...             
5410906 651.8   524 4369    ...             
MSG 5410907 buffer1                         
5410907 651.3   524.7   4373    ...             
5410908 650.7   525.4   4377    ...             
5410909 651.2   525.9   4383    ...             
MSG 5410910 Diode1                          
5410910 651.7   525.5   4384    ...             
5410911 652.1   525.4   4378    ...             
5410912 652 525.5   4372    ...             
5410913 651.9   526 4365    ...             
5410914 651.8   526.3   4363    ...             
5410915 651.6   527 4362    ...             
5410916 651.5   527.7   4362    ...             
5410917 652 528.6   4365    ...             
5410918 652.5   528.8   4369    ...             
5410919 653 528.3   4371    ...             
5410920 652.9   527.1   4371    ...             
5410921 652.8   525.9   4371    ...             
5410922 652.8   524.3   4378    ...             
5410923 652.3   523.1   4388    ...             
5410924 651.9   522.7   4397    ...             
5410925 651.1   523.4   4398    ...             
5410926 650.9   524.3   4399    ...             
5410927 650.7   524.2   4397    ...             
5410928 650.8   524.1   4395    ...             
5410929 650.8   524 4394    ...             
5410930 650.7   525.3   4386    ...             
5410931 651.2   526.4   4379    ...             
5410932 651.9   527.3   4372    ...             
5410933 652.7   526.5   4374    ...             
5410934 652.8   525.6   4375    ...             
5410935 653 524.8   4376    ...             
5410936 653.2   524.6   4376    ...             
5410937 653.5   524.6   4373    ...             
5410938 653.5   524.7   4372    ...             
5410939 652.9   524.7   4371    ...             
5410940 652.1   525.7   4372    ...             
5410941 651.2   526.6   4372    ...             
5410942 651.1   527.5   4372    ...             
5410943 651.2   527.9   4372    ...             
5410944 651.1   528.7   4373    ...             
5410945 650.9   529.4   4374    ...             
5410946 651 528.7   4374    ...             
5410947 651.2   527.7   4374    ...             
5410948 651.5   525.7   4374    ...             
5410949 651.4   524.8   4374    ...             
5410950 651.3   525.2   4375    ...             
5410951 651 526.4   4376    ...             
5410952 650.7   527.4   4382    ...             
5410953 650.5   527.2   4389    ...             
5410954 650.6   527 4396    ...             
5410955 650.6   527.1   4394    ...
```

Delimiters are \t in the csv file if that helps.

As can be seen the data is written row-after-row sequentially from top-to-bottom instead of being organised into columns as I want to shape them.

I've reshaped from short to long before but have no idea where to start with this.

Thanks for taking the time to read.

Comment: Can you also show the raw data? or the `str()` of the resulting data.frame? Are you leaving out values with the `...` or is that a literal value in the file? I'm also not sure I understand your description of the expected output for the same above, can you be even more explicit about how multiple rows are condensed?

Comment: Hi MrFlick. I've added example of raw data. The ... are values in the raw data but I will not need them. I aim to condense the data into rows by the 'MSG   5410895 start_trial' in the csv where I've added a trial type 'SCNB' as an identifier, as well as having 2 separate columns for the x & y CoOr (651.6 & 524.6 values after the time stamp) & I also want a column for the time stamp. Additionally I want to have a column that will repeat labels such as 'PreBeep1_1st_Sketchpad' &'crosshair' until encountering next label. If someone can point me in the best direction that'd be great. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible strategy. First, just read the data in as a character vector of lines. THis is what I assume your input data looks like

```
MSG 12892743 start_trial 1 SCNB
12892743      757.0   361.7  5916.0 ... SCNB
MSG 12892744 PreBeep1_1st_Sketchpad SCNB
12892744      756.7   361.7  5920.0 ... SCNB
12892745      756.1   362.2  5924.0 ... SCNB
MSG 12892746 order of frames:   SCNB
12892746      755.8   362.3  5928.0 ... SCNB
12892747      756.7   362.3  5927.0 ... SCNB
MSG 12892748 crosshair  SCNB
12892748      757.8   361.8  5928.0 ... SCNB
12892749      758.4   361.8  5930.0 ... SCNB
MSG 12892750 sketchpad  SCNB
12892750      758.1   361.7  5934.0 ... SCNB
12892751      758.3   361.7  5938.0 ... SCNB
MSG 12892752 sketchpad  SCNB
12892752      759.1   361.9  5948.0 ... SCNB
12892753      760.4   362.7  5956.0 ... SCNB
MSG 12892754 sketchpad  SCNB
```

and we read that with

```
xx <- readLines("filename.txt")
```

Now, we format the different row types and extract the values

```
data <- lapply(strsplit(xx, "\\s+"), function(x) {
    if(x[1]=="MSG") {
        return(list(id=x[length(x)], 
            frame=paste(x[-c(1:2, length(x))], collapse=" ")))
    } else {
        return(list(x=x[2], y=x[3], t=x[4]))
    }
})
```

Now we need to merge this data in. First, we create a template for each row

```
row<-setNames(replicate(5, character()), c("id","frame","x","y","t"))
```

Now we use Reduce to go though each list and update the current row with the values from the data. If we have x,y and t values, then we set a flag letting us know the record is complete, then we extract only the complete records

```
rows<-Filter(function(x) !is.null(x$out) && x$out==1, Reduce(function(a,b) {
    z<-modifyList(a,b); 
    if("x" %in% names(b)) {
        z$out=1
    } else {
        z$out=0
    }
    z
}, data, row, accumulate=T))
```

Finally, we combine all the rows into a matrix

```
do.call(rbind, rows)
```

Obviously this is a bit messy but your data format is a bit messy. Perhaps you can at least use this as a starting point.

Comment: That's great thanks. I'll have a play with this and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I'm currently playing with your code but once I get as far as rows<-Filter(function(x)... code I get the following error:  Error: is.list(val) is not TRUE. Any ideas? I'll try and fix it and update if I do.

Comment: Did you create the `row` list first? The the `data` variable look like a list of lists?

Comment: I did run the row code yup, and it created all the columns with chr(0). For clarity I'm assuming we are manipulating the csv file (as it has appended data) rather than the source asc.

Comment: Oh. I was using the raw data because the structure of your CSV data wasn't at all clear. I couldn't tell if that was a data.frame or what or how many columns it had or where the commas were.

Comment: Oh right, sorry for the confusion. The csv file simply copies the asc file contents (after filtering out what I don't need) using \t as the delimiter. I added extra data, namely the trial IDs (e.g. SCNB) which are also separated by /t.

Comment: So is that the output above? Did you also add line numbers or is that the output from R? What are you supposed to do with the first line (`12892743      757.0   361.7  5916.0 ... SCNB`) there's no frame information for that line.

Comment: The 1st example is output once csv is put directly into a dataframe. The line nums are from R. The line numbered 1 is actually the second line and R assumes line 1 is the column name. It appears my post has been edited to look as though the 1st line is the name of the dataframe which isn't the case. The line 12892743 757.0 361.7 5916.0 ... SCNB comes under MSG.12892743.start_trial.1.SCNB. This is basically telling us that when the MSG was sent for frame 'start_trial' (a frame here is simply a label given to an image presented. Think animation) the values below are time, x, y, number, trial ID.

Comment: Apologise for being a pain in the butt. Getting 'Error in x$out : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors' when running rows<-Filter(function(x)... code. Still playing with it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56964/discussion-between-mrflick-and-docconcoct).

Comment: Hi again MrFlick. Your code works wonderfully in principal but due to my data file having close to 2 million observations (eye tracking coordinates for every millisecond recorded)  my computer cannot handle this in memory. I was wondering if it was possible to perhaps use your solution above but instead write a single line at a time into a new csv file in the desired column format? I'm guessing that I'd need some kind of loop on the function in order to do this?

Comment: R might not be the best language for that. Personally i'd use Perl for that type of transformation.